# Abnormal Workbench Condition in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, windows-7-x64, cfeclipse

Occasionally, I get the follow error when working in Eclipse. Restarting the app fixes the problem, but it is very annoying, and it happens all to frequently. I have 8GB of RAM on my desktop running Win7 x64, and I have the following configured in `eclipse.ini`

```
-vmargs
-Xms1092m
-Xmx2056m
```

[image]

I am running CFEclipse as a plugin, as well as subclipse. I have the latest JavaVM (x64).

Does anyone else experience this problem? And is there a solution?

Comment: Is there a pattern? Like copy/pasting a long text, trying to autocomplete or something  that happens before you get the error?

Comment: Are there any more details in the Error Log (ie, the rest of the stack trace)?  (Window -> Show View -> Error log)

Comment: @Jhurtado: The error occurs when I'm just typing along. It does seem to happen more often when I'm trying to cut-and-paste or copy-and-paste, but just using the backspace sometimes causes the issue.

Comment: @Andrew here's the error log http://pastebin.com/ALHMa246

Comment: I raised https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334170, you can add any details there.  Perhaps which editor you are in when it happens.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same/a similar problem and a similar environment. Running 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' (Build id: 20110916-0149), CFEclipse plugin on Win 2003 64 bit with stacks of RAM. If I had more rep I'd start a bounty!

Comment: Nope. Like @AndrewNiefer said, it's probably a bug in CFEclipse. my solution was to stop using CFEclipse :P